# nginx configuration for a nodejs app and laravel app together

Tags: laravel, nginx, next.js

So I have a web app project on my server with 2 directories:
1) frontend - a nodejs app (next.js) that I start with pm2.
2) api - the laravel backend api

I also the have nginx installed and tried this as my server settings:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /project/api/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Now when i go to my web address the frontend part works so when i go to example.com I see my web app (so the config for the proxy to port 3000 works).

Howvever the backend/api does not work, i think because it does not redirect to the api when i perform a backend task. like 
http://example.com:3000/api/auth/login/ should go to my laravel app.

"/api/..." is the backend endpoints.

I think I need to somehow define a location /api {} to go to the laravel app.

Any help to get ths working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 "location /" definitions...  One is clobbering the other.

Try using the following for your second definition:

```php
location /api {
    try_files $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: for that I get a 504 Gateway Timeout. do you know if the rest of my settings seem alright for laravel?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about your server configuration.  Are you running a Red Hat or Debian variant?  I can try to help walk you through it.  Can you provide the last stack trace in your /var/log/nginx/error.log file?

Comment: I'd also suggest adding these two lines to the bottom of your `location /` section...  Currently, your proxy setup doesn't forward errors properly.  These two lines should help fix it:

```php
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

Comment: I am running Ubuntu. this is the error log:
2019/02/11 18:31:48 [emerg] 17991#17991: unknown directive "php" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:9. The 504 error comes after a request to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login/ so i guess its not proxying to the api correctly?

Comment: Don't use "localhost:3000" at all...  Your goal  is to get nginx working on port 80.  http://localhost should show the same thing as localhost:3000...  If its not, something else is wrong with your nginx setup.  To answer your question about proxying correctly, it's not proxying at all...  You're not hitting nginx at all...  You're hitting Node's web server directly.

Comment: If you type `sudo service nginx status` what is listed after `Active:` ?

Comment: says it is active running, which is right. I guess first thing Ill do now is make my node app run on port 80 instead of 3000

Comment: You won't be able to do that...  Nginx is already running on port 80.

Comment: Your setup for proxying NGINX to point to your node app, if not already correct, looks like it's headed in the right direction.  If you navigate to localhost, you're node app is not currently displaying?

Comment: yeah it works actually, it shows my app. so i guess then its just the routing, and like i said when I call this endpoint localhost:3000/api/auth/login  from my node app, it should call the laravel app

Comment: Correct...  To double check the api, try going to localhost/api/<some public endpoint> and see if that works...  you may have to create yourself an endpoint to test against.